# What happens when response timeout in nginx+uwsgi+django?

Tags: django, nginx, blocking, uwsgi

I have a long running task which is NOT async, it will block the response of django, the server stack is nginx+uwsgi, what happens after nginx decide it's timeout, will my task (the uwsgi worker and the django view thread) be killed?

Comment: Are you sure there's a timeout on the server side? It might just be the client timing out after not getting a response for so many seconds...

Comment: @Cameron Yes I am sure it's a server timeout the page says 504 timeout with nginx version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

normally the request will continue in uWSGI until a "bad condition" (like sending a chunk of the response to a disconnected client) will fail. It is a configurable behaviour, but i suggest you to not touch it if you have no VERY specific reasons

Comment: so if nginx shows 504 to the client, my process task will continue, but the return response will fail?

Comment: yes, exactly. Basically the backend knows about the disconnection only when it tries to access the socket.

Comment: Thanks. It's good to hear there's no forced kill timeout process behavior in uwsgi.